# как принимать введенный текст пользователя телеграм бот (Python, Telebot)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, telegram

подскажите как можно принять введённый текст пользователя

```
import telebot


bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')
keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
keyboard1 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
keyboard.row('СМС', 'Звонки')
keyboard1.row('Назад')
phone = ''

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_messages(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Какой тип сообщения вы бы хотели сделать ?", reply_markup = keyboard)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def after_text(message):
    if message.text == 'СМС':
        input1 = message.text
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите номер телефона: ', reply_markup = keyboard1)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, after_text)
    elif message.text == 'Звонки':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Скоро будет...', reply_markup = keyboard1)
    elif message.text == 'Назад':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Какой тип сообщения вы бы хотели сделать ?', reply_markup = keyboard)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Я вас не понимаю')

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Видел в интернете пишут что надо использовать **bot.register_next_step_handler(message, after_text)** А что дальше то, как сделать что бы переменная **phone** принимала значение введённого номера человека ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def after_text(message):
    if message.text == 'СМС':
        msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите номер телефона: ', reply_markup = keyboard1)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, after_text_2)
...


def after_text_2(message):
   print('введённый пользователем номер телефона на шаге "смс":', message.text)
```

`bot.register_next_step_handler` принимает два аргумента:

- кому\куда/что отправить
- к какому шагу (функции) перейти

после отправки `msg` выполняется ожидание ввода, с последующим "пробросом" в функцию указанную вторым аргументом.

*это если на пальцах.*

Comment: Спасибо, вот теперь понятно)

Comment: если вам нужно передать аргумент в "шаг" используйте `bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, after_text_2, arg)`; `function(message, arg)`