# Аргумент в сообщении бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Как проверить у команды аргумент?

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "/test":
        if arg is None:
            bot.reply_to(message, "Напишите: /test text")
        else:
            bot.reply_to(message, "test")
```

Я получал arg в самой функции, но программа ломалась.
Как можно получить после "/test" текст который ввел пользователь?
Данный вариант не подходит: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1254633/как-принимать-введенный-текст-пользователя-телеграм-бот-python-telebot](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1254633/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82-python-telebot) 
Не хочу разделять сообщения:
`Я: /test Бот: Введите аргумент Я: 123 Бот: test`
Хочу:
`Я: /test 123 Бот: test *Если аргумента нет* Я: /test\ Бот: Напишите: /test аргумент`

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Использовать машины состояний, FSM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень просто, аргументы в команде - обычный текст:

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    args = message.text.split() # 0 -> /text, 1 -> test, 2 -> test2

    if len(args) < 2:
        return bot.reply_to(message, "Напишите: /test text")
    
    bot.reply_to(message, args[1])
```

Comment: Я понял, спасибо.
Но, не получается сделать "триггер" на команду.
А также проверка не проходит нормально. Если кроме команды ничего не написал, то программа закрывается (return убирал, также).

Comment: Точно, исправил, можете тестить

Comment: Когда нет аргументов, программа также вылетает. Ошибка: что не может вывести args[1], хотя должен вывести ```return```

Comment: Попробуйте сейчас :)

Comment: Спасибо. Получилось. Чуть изменил:
if len(args) <= 1: return # etc..