# Как остановить цикл и продолжить telebot Python

Tags: python, циклы, telebot

Отрывок из кода

```
elif call.data == "sound":
   path = "/root/sound"
   path1 = (os.listdir(path))
   for i in path1:
      audio = open(f"{i}", "rb")
      bot.send_audio(call.message.chat.id,audio)
```

По пути /root/sound находятся звуки, их достаточно много, как можно сделать так, чтобы к примеру отправлялось 10 звуков, затем пользователя спрашивали, хотите продолжить ? И ему отправлялись следующие 10 звуков

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, есть несколько вариантов решения...один из: ограничьте цикл до n прохождений и отправляя последнее сообщение, добавьте клавиатуру где в data укажите текущий прогресс. Далее... ловите call, вытаскиваете прогресс из data и продолжаете отправку с учетом этого.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать так:

```
   elif call.data == "sound":
   path = "/root/sound"
   path1 = (os.listdir(path))
   sounds = 0
   for i in path1:
      sounds += 1
      audio = open(f"{i}", "rb")
      bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,audio)
      if sounds % 10 == 0:
         if input('Хотите продолжить?\n') != 'да':
            break
```

Comment: А как можно реализовать чтобы пользователь в боте вводил «да» ? Через register не подходит

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1254633/ - можете посмотреть тут

Comment: А ещё в Telebot вроде можно создавать кнопки.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать